# Is a bounded and continuous function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

$f\colon(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous does it mean that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Well, $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ does the job for counterexample? Please help!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315555/an-example-of-a-bounded-continuous-function-on-0-1-that-is-not-uniformly-co

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're close: $$\sin\frac{1}{x+1}$$ is a counterexample to the statement.

Answer (score 9):

For continuity to lead to uniform continuity, domain has to be compact, and as you can see the domain is not compact here. Also, rightly
$f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x+1}) $ serves as a counterexample.

Comment: $\sin(e^x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks. Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

$\sin(x^2)$ is also a nice example and it's happening because it's not periodic.

Comment: This function is continuous on $[-1,1]$, so it is uniformly continuous there. A fortiori on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Over the real line, this is, not on any bounded interval.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Although its a nice counterexample to show that a bounded function on a closed, but unbounded interval is not necessarily uniformly continuous.