# An example of a bounded, continuous function on $(0,1)$ that is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

I can not find the example of a continuous function on $(0,1)$ that is bounded on $(0,1)$, but not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. Is there any? Thank you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220733/is-a-bounded-and-continuous-function-uniformly-continuous

Answer (score 14):

If you are not aware of the result mentioned in the example of @Tomek Kania,Here is elementary approach to prove that $\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.
$$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
It is certainly bounded. However, it is not uniformly continuous. Given $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$, for any $\delta\gt 0$ we can find a large enough value of $n$ so that 
$$\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi} - \frac{1}{2n\pi} = \frac{4n - (2n+1)}{2n(2n+1)\pi} = \frac{2n-1}{2n(2n+1)\pi}\lt \delta,$$
yet 
$$f\left(\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}\right) =\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right) = \pm 1,$$ and $$f\left(\frac{1}{2n\pi}\right) = \sin(2n\pi) = 0,$$ so letting $x=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$ and $y=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$, we have
$$|x-y|\lt\delta\text{ but }|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \epsilon.$$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/how-to-prove-sin1-x-is-not-uniformly-continuous

Answer (score 10):

Take $$f(x) = \sin 1/x.$$

It is not uniformly continuous as [such functions admit continuous extension to the closure of the domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96657/continuous-extension-of-a-uniformly-continuous-function-from-a-dense-subset). Here we don't have such extension as there are two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $(0,1)$ that tend to 0 such that $f(x_n)=1$ and $f(y_n)=0$ for all $n$.